# How do I use a single neuron layer in the multiple layers of a multilayer network?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, mlp

Is it conceptually wrong to put a layer of multiple neurons after a single layer of neurons? if yes, How do I use this single neuron layer in the multiple layers of a multilayer network?

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Input(shape=(10,))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
```

Do I have to use a special layer? How?

In my application, the single neuron layer is a sum layer, which is as follows:

```
class sumLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(DefuzzyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def call(self, x_inputs):
    xc = K.sum((x_inputs), axis=-1, keepdims=False)
    return tf.reshape(xc,(tf.shape(x_inputs)[0],1))
```

Comment: It depends on your application: In the example you gave, this 1-neuron layer would be an information bottleneck. This is common in things like Autoencoders or GANs. So 'conceptually wrong' only makes sense if you talk about specific applications.

Comment: thanks a lot, in my application single neuron layer is a sumlayer that I edited above. Is it conceptually wrong?

Comment: I'd say that it's not really a 'neuron' because it includes no trainable parameters, so it cannot learn anything. It is still impossible to say if what you are doing is 'wrong' because it depends on the task you try to solve.
What's happening in your `sumLayer` is feature summation, in that case, you need to be careful that your output value doesn't get too large which would make training harder for subsequent layers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely non standard to have any point in a deep neural network, where representation is collapsed to a single number. This creates an extreme information bottleneck, and thus, while in theory every complex decision can still be encoded, it will become extremely hard for the next layer to learn to reason about this space, if they need to react in a way that is not a very simple "thresholding" of your signal on the line. So, is it conceptually "wrong"? No, it is not really affecting representational power. Is it **risky**? Yes, it is something that experienced practicioners would never do **unless there is a well understood reason to go this way**.

To gain some intuition: one of the core reasons of effectiveness of neural networks is that they operate in *very highly dimensional spaces*, where their simple, affine transformations (neurons) can achieve surprising degree of data separation, but more importantly - they can be trained using extremely naive optimisation methods (gradient descent). These properties will **be completely gone** once dimensionality is reduced. In particular with an extreme representational bottleneck you are **much more likely to be affected by local minima**, that the early neural network community was struggling with (an issue that somewhat "magically" went away with the scale, and dimensionality going up; there is a whole field of research, e.g. Neural Tangent Kernels that provide mathematical fundations/understanding of why this is the case in high dimension).